# The term "maximal solution" for PDE

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, terminology

> A solution $x(t)$ of the ODE is called maximal if it is defined on an
>   open interval and cannot be extended to any larger open interval.

from "Ordinary Differential Equation". Alexander Grigorian. University of Bielefeld. Lecture Notes, April - July 2008.

How the term "maximal solution" is defined for PDE? Is it a maximum connected set on which there is a continuation for a solution?

Comment: This is an interesting question because potentially you could have domains $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$, both containing some $U$ that you insist must be a subset of the domain of a solution, with the property that no solution exists on a larger open set, but $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ are different.  So which $\Omega$ is better?  This problem does not happen in one dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define it in the same manner for PDEs but I don't remember ever seeing it used mostly because unlike *ODEs* there is no theorem in *PDE* theory that guarantees the existence of a maximal solution as far as I know.

Comment: But how the "physical" solutions of general relativity can be defined? If we don't require maximality of the solution domain, then our world would be seriously damaged by having a solution only 1cm in size instead of the full universe

Comment: **Some** PDEs do have a maximal solution but **not all**. One may have PDEs that have local solutions and it may not be possible to "glue" all the local solutions together to form a global solution.